# How to pass variable consisting of symbol and integers in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

We have the following Ruby code to access data from a Mongo database using MongoMapper:

```
@blah = Foo.where( :bar.gte => 2.5, :pub => @loo  ).all
```

We would like to vary the conditions passed into the database call, but how do we handle the presence of symbols and variables name?

In other words, the following doesn't work:

```
conditions = :bar.gte => 2.5, :pub => @loo
@blah = Foo.where( conditions  ).all
```

How can we put the conditions into a variable?

Comment: I am not sure if a string would work as condition in MongoMapper ORM. But you can try: `conditions = {'bar.gte' => 2.5, 'pub' => @loo}` then `Foo.where(conditions)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to assign it as a hash:

```
conditions = {:bar.gte => 2.5, :pub => @loo}
```

And yes, `:bar.gte` *is* a valid key. MongoMapper defines [`Symbol#gte`](https://github.com/mongomapper/plucky/blob/master/lib/plucky/extensions/symbol.rb#L13) which returns a `SymbolOperator` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Pass it as a hash?

<s>`conditions = {:bar.gte => 2.5, :pub => @loo}`</s>

Edit:

Didn't notice that your first key had a period.

`conditions = {'bar.gte' => 2.5, :pub => @loo}`

Comment: Did you even try running the above code before posting?

Comment: @kp666: `:bar.gte` is not a valid Hash key.

Comment: @Surya No, I didn't. However OP's primary concern was in knowing how to pass multiple conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it in a hash, but also use strings for complex keys:

```
conditions = {'bar.gte' => 2.5, :pub => @loo}
@blah = Foo.where( conditions  ).all
```

Comment: so we don't need symbols for complex keys?

Comment: I can't test this right now, but I know you can't generally use a method call on a symbol, but I would expect that using a string like so would achieve the same result (presumably you want the `gte` column in the `bar` table?).